# Can I use $emit/$broadcast and callbacks together?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on my first angular application and am trying to make it as modular as possible. My application clicks through 'screens' each screen has its own controller based on its type. The content for the screen comes from an api - text, image and audio.

I need to be able to determine how items are loaded on the page. I have a sequence in my API.

```
var sequence =  [
            [
                {
                    "item": 't1',
                    "type": 'fadeUp'
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "item": 't2',
                    "type": 'fadeUp'
                },
                {
                    "item": 'a1'
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "item": 't3',
                    "type": 'fadeUp'
                },
                {
                    "item": 'i1',
                    "type": 'fadeUp'
                },
                {
                    "item": 'a2'
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "item": 't4',
                    "type": 'fadeUp'
                }
            ]
        ];
```

There are 4 steps in this sequence and I don't want it to move onto the next one until all the sub-items are completed. eg/ dont move onto the next step until the audio has finished playing - How can I do this?

At the moment I'm using $emit which the relevant controllers pick up and display the content but it all happens at once because I'm looping through the second level of the array without any delay. I assume I need to use $q.all? but i'm not sure what this would look like?

an example of my code: I couldn't get an example working :(

Factory:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var sequenceFactory = function (clinicalCasesSettings, $rootScope, $timeout, utils, $q) {

        var factory = {};

        factory.startSequence = function (sequence, screen) {
            _.each(screen.sequence, function (sequencePos, i) {
                console.info('SEQUENCE ' + i);
                _.each(sequencePos, function (action) {
                    var actionType = _determineActionType(action.item);
                    $rootScope.$emit('start' + utils.ucFirst(actionType), i);

                });


            });
        }

        // helper methods for the factory
        function _determineActionType(item) {
            var actionType;
            actionType = item.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, "");
            return clinicalCasesSettings.actionTypes[actionType];
        }

        return factory;
    };

    sequenceFactory.$inject = ['clinicalCasesSettings', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'utils', '$q'];

    angular.module('clinicalCases').factory('sequenceFactory', sequenceFactory);

}());
```

One of the Controllers listening to the $emit

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var textImageController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $state, $timeout, sequenceFactory) {
        console.log('textImageController loaded');

        //@TODO I dont think this is the right way to do this?
        var inheritedScope = $scope.$parent.$parent;

        //Just in case another image sneaks in
        $scope.image = inheritedScope.screen.image[0].src;
        $scope.content = '';



        $rootScope.$on('startText', function (event, data) {
                $scope.content += inheritedScope.screen.textContent[data].content;
        });




        sequenceFactory.startSequence(inheritedScope.screen.sequence, inheritedScope.screen);

    };
    textImageController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$state', '$timeout', 'sequenceFactory'];
    angular.module('clinicalCases').controller('textImageController', textImageController);
}());
```

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: instead of `var inheritedScope = $scope.$parent.$parent;` use a service to share data between controllers. Will appreciate it later when you don't have to figure out what `$parent.$parent` is or if you even have the right level

Comment: How are you determining when part of the sequence is complete?

Comment: @HankScorpio That was my question! :D

Comment: @charlietfl thank you, I will add that to my todo!